# Setting the Storyboard ID programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I work on a team and one of the storyboards that I require was done programmatically, which is fine. I am currently trying to pass data using delegates from one viewcontroller (the programmatically done VC) to another (interface builder built storyboard).

The code for one VC (sender) is:

```
protocol setDelegate {
    func passData(_ area: String, _ location: String)
}

class ProgramaticVC : UIViewController {
    var delegate: setDelegate?

    ...

    func passData() {
        self.delegate?.passData(area, location)
        let interfaceBuilderVC = UIStoryboard.init("Main", nil).instantiateViewController("interfaceBuilderVC") as! InterfaceBuilderVC
        show(interfaceBuilderVC, nil)
    }
```

The receiver code:

```
class InterfaceBuilderVC : UIViewController {

    ...

func passData(_ area: String, _ location: String) {
     areaLabel.text = area
     locationLabel.text = location
     // Not sure how to set the delegate, but what I was thinking:
     let programmaticVC = UIStoryboard.init("Main", nil).instantiateViewController("CAN'T SET ID") as! ProgrammaticVC
     programmaticVC.delegate = self
}
```

So I am either looking to set the ID for the storyboard programmatically, or perhaps get any other advice on how to set my delegate correctly.

Comment: when you use delegate to pass data between viewcontrollers, you need to connect them somehow. where's that approach? why you trying to instantiate Storyboard? what is the purpose? [Have a look at this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers)

Comment: You can't set the storyboard Id programmatically. If your storyboard doesn't contain a scene for your view controller then you will need to instantiate your view controller using a simple initialiser. That said, you wouldn't be instantiating it in `passData`; that is the method that is going to receive the data from the viewcontroller that already exists. Similarly, in your first `passData()`, you are invoking the delegate method on a view controller that should already exist and then showing a new instance of a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use a delegate if all you want to do is send data from one view controller to the other. You could simply do this:

```
class ProgramaticVC : UIViewController {

    func passData() {
        let interfaceBuilderVC = UIStoryboard.init("Main", nil).instantiateViewController("interfaceBuilderVC") as! InterfaceBuilderVC
        interfaceBuilderVC.area = area
        interfaceBuilderVC.location = location
        show(interfaceBuilderVC, nil)
    }
}
```

and

```
class InterfaceBuilderVC : UIViewController {

    var area: String?
    var location: String?
}
```

You might want to use a delegate if your `InterfaceBuilderVC` needs to communicate back to `ProgramaticVC`, but it's not clear from your question that this is what you want to do.